# how to make the recaptcha image smaller (to one word)

Tags: php, css, recaptcha

I'm using the custom theme of recaptcha, and the designer want that the recaptcha's image will be smaller in the width but not in the height. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reCAPTCHA is served via an Iframe on a different domain, therefore you cannot alter what it serves-up.

If you could alter it, so could malicious scripts.